# How to parse through multi array json data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have multi array json response through an API call in Angularjs. But on iterating the values through ng-repeat, array values are splitting into each character. I don't understand how to parse it.

for e.g. it is supposed to iterate 'color-green', but I am getting it as `'c','o','l','o','r','g','r','e','e','n'`... Can you please help me on getting it. Below is the plnkr link

http://plnkr.co/edit/gppDyJ4FJ9x78aDkiwMW?p=preview

The portion of my code that iterates is:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'colors.json'}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = [];
    angular.forEach(data.colors, function(value, key) {         
        $scope.colorList = value;       
    });     
});
```

And the `colors.json` file contains:

```
{
    "colors": {
         "blue":["color-blue","color-blue-08","color-blue-06","color-blue-04","color-blue-02"],
         "red":["color-red","color-red-08","color-red-06","color-red-04","color-red-02"],
         "skyblue":["color-skyblue","color-skyblue-08","color-skyblue-06","color-skyblue-04","color-skyblue-02"],
         "orange":["color-orange","color-orange-08","color-orange-06","color-orange-04","color-orange-02"],
         "grey":["color-grey","color-grey-08","color-grey-06","color-grey-04","color-grey-02"],
         "green":["color-green","color-green-08","color-green-06","color-green-04","color-green-02"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have helped with some formatting issues and added the relevant portions of your code into the question, in case the plunkr is not available anymore later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
There was a little mistake in the way your were getting the values into the 
scope

I've forked your pluker.
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/77Eg7KJOl1SPVG14sAoD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the objects to the array rather than assigning them

```
angular.forEach(data.colors, function(value, key) {
        $scope.colorList.push(value);
});
```

[CORRECTED DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/s6KFDDxOW3EHU5IICxDK?p=preview)